# Do I need to know users device ID or Device Token to send notifications to them?

Tags: iphone

How to send Notification to all those users who have downloaded my applications from apple store?

Do I need to know users device ID or Device Token to send notifications to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're referring to push notifications, you'll need to have the users' device tokens in order to send a notification to their devices.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Alternatively (another meaning):
Write them a note in an update. Or write it in the app description in the app store.