# Error when run test vue with MSAL configuration

Tags: vue.js, testing, msal

I have a vue application with MSAL of Azure configuration. My application runs well and without any problems. But when I create my first test, it returns this error:

```
src/msalConfiguration.ts:8:1 - error TS1378: Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', or 'nodenext', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.

    8 await msalInstance.initialize();
```

My msalConfiguration is like this:

```
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import AzureService from "./services/azure.service";

const azureService = new AzureService();
const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(
  azureService.getMsalConfig().value
);
await msalInstance.initialize();

export default msalInstance;
```

And I have changed the tsconfig.js and I have this:
"target": "es2017",
"module": "esnext",

So I have the same that the error says. I'm getting crazy because I can't continue with my tests and I have not idea how to solve it.

My test is like this:

```
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import DashboardView from "@/views/dashboard/DashboardView.vue";
import InfoCard from "@/components/cards/InfoCard.vue";
import { routes } from "@/constants/routes";
import { Row, Col, Card, Divider } from "ant-design-vue";
import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from "vue-router";
import msalInstance from "@/msalConfiguration";

const fakeTranslations = {
  en: {
    models: "Models",
    experiments: "Experiments",
    dashboard_page: {
      more_info: "More info",
      execution_mode: "Execution mode",
      model_serving: "Model serving",
    },
  },
};

window.matchMedia = jest.fn().mockImplementation((query) => {
  return {
    matches: true,
    media: query,
    onchange: null,
    addListener: jest.fn(),
    removeListener: jest.fn(),
  };
});

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes,
});

describe("DashboardView.vue", () => {
  it("renders the component", async () => {
    const i18n = createI18n({
      locale: "en",
      messages: fakeTranslations,
    });
    const wrapper = mount(DashboardView, {
      global: {
        plugins: [i18n, router],
        components: {
          "a-row": Row,
          "a-divider": Divider,
          "a-col": Col,
          "a-card": Card,
          "info-card": InfoCard,
          "font-awesome-icon": FontAwesomeIcon,
          "router-link": {
            render: () => {},
          },
          msalInstance: msalInstance,
        },
      },
    });

    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

I have tried different alternative, like create a mock of msal, import msal in the components of the wrapper... but I can't find the solution ...

Comment: [Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73884361).  No official answer, but read the comments.  It's the jest testing framework that doesn't support top-level await.  You can attempt configuring jest to work with ESM, or refactor your code to not use top-level await, or use different testing framework.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do i need to know users device ID or Device Token to send notifications to them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884311/do-i-need-to-know-users-device-id-or-device-token-to-send-notifications-to-them)